# ClassCastException when using DataNucleus JPAReplicationManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, datanucleus

I am trying to test DataNucleus JPAReplicationManager but is not working so far.

In my classpath I have:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
datanucleus-api-jpa-4.1.0-m1.jar
datanucleus-core-4.1.0-m1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar
```

Here is my code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf1 = master.getDbFactory();
EntityManagerFactory emf2 = slave.getDbFactory();

JPAReplicationManager replicator = new JPAReplicationManager(emf1, emf2);
replicator.replicate(new Class[]{Terminal.class});
```

The error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl cannot be cast to org.datanucleus.ExecutionContext
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAReplicationManager.replicate(JPAReplicationManager.java:133)
```

Comment: So apparently one persistence unit is managed by Hibernate, and the other persistence unit is managed by datanucleus? The exception seems to want to tell you that this is not supported, most likely both persistence units need to be governed by datanucleus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you use DataNucleus replication facilities, yet try to use a Hibernate EntityManagerFactory. Since DataNucleus replication requires DataNucleus specifics both EMFs should be from DataNucleus